# TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This is index js file.

```
    import React from "react";
    import { render } from "react-dom";
    import {Router, Route, browserHistory} from "react-router";

    import {EmployeeList} from "./employeeList";
    import {EditForm} from "./edit";


    class App extends React. Component{ 
        render(){
            return (
                <Router history={browserHistory}>
                    <Route path={"/"} component={EmployeeList} />   
                </Router>
            );
        }
    }

    render(<App />, window.document.getElementById("app"));
```

This is employeeList js file.

```
    import React from "react";

    export class EmployeeList extends React. Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        };

        render() {
                return (
                <div>
                    <h2>Basic Table</h2>

                    <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Button</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        {student}
                    </table>
                </div>
            );

        }
    }
```

Main page is index.js  from that page i want call employeeList page..but its showing undefined location type error.install npm react-route too still its not working..unable to find out the error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `BrowserRouter` from `'react-router-dom'` instead of the `Router`.

The Router component is intended to be used when working with a custom history, so the `history` prop is required. To work with the react-router on the web browser, you should use the BrowserRouter from `react-router-dom`. Just for clarity, here is the [Router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Router), and the [BrowserRouter docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter)

And your code should be:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

...

```
class App extends React. Component{ 
    render(){
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Route path={"/"} component={EmployeeList} />   
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```